# Webpack 2 UMD library object empty

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I'm trying to write a UMD library in Webpack that is broken up into multiple files that can be manually loaded. It's not my preference (at all), but that's part of the requirements.

I've got the CommonsChunkPlugin working that extracts all of the libraries and files to their own loadable files. Here's the Webpack config file:

```
let plugins = [ new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'gm-components',
  filename: '[name].js',
  minChunks(module, count) {
    let context = module.context;
    let chunk = module.chunks && module.chunks[0];
    return ( chunk && chunk.name == 'components.js' ) ||
     ( context && context.match(/preact|prop-types/i) );
    }
 }),
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'gm-dates',
  filename: '[name].js',
  chunks: ['dates.js', 'gm-misc.js', 'gm-cart.js'],
  minChunks(module, count) {
    let context = module.context;
    let chunk = module.chunks && module.chunks[0];
    return ( chunk && chunk.name == 'dates.js' ) ||
      ( context && context.match(/supercal|fecha/i) );
    }
})];

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "components.js":       './src/js/components.js',
    "dates.js":            "./src/js/dates.js",
    "gm-misc.js":          "./src/js/misc.js",
    "gm-cart.js":          "./src/js/cart.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
    filename: '[name]',
    library: 'GMComponents',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
  }
};
```

All the files in `src` are pretty self-contained, but I wish to have a universally available constructor function for the components. In `src/js/components.js` I have this code:

```
import { render as domRender} from 'react-dom';
import React, { createElement } from 'react';

export var components = {};
export var render = (ele, name, props, callback) => {
  let klass = components[name];
  let comp = createElement(klass, props || {});
  return domRender(comp, ele, callback);
};
```

Unfortunately all that I get in `window.GMComponents` is an empty object. Does the CommonsChunkPlugin make it impossible for me to include universally available functions?

Comment: I'm thinking that the object is overwritten with every script include, actual.

Comment: More than likely I'm approaching this all wrong and just need to not put in the library part of the configuration, do it more manual style.

Comment: That's a tricky one. But, just going by logic, if you wish to expose an object to the global scope (`window` in this case), your `libraryTarget` should be `this` or whatever configuration attach your object to the global scope